# Dealing with classes introduced in a later Android version

Tags: java, android

Assume I have an app with many functionalities, one of them is using `android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt` available only since Android API 18. But my app should also work on older API versions.

**Can I always write**

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
    BluetoothGatt gatt = null;
    ...
}
```

and use this activity without problems on phones with API versions older than 18 without running into any troubles, as long as my code **in practice** never reaches an instruction where some constant or method not yet available is used? For instance, in a method of `ActivityMain`, I would write

```
BluetoothDevice device = ...

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18)
    gatt = device.connectGatt(...)
```

in order to make sure that `gatt` stays `null` if `BluetoothGatt` is not yet supported.

If my approach does not work, what can I do instead?

Comment: I guess your code will work just fine, make sure you do null checks before accessing `gatt`.

Comment: i don't mean to be rude, but the simple answer is : test it. i think your question is completely valid, but you _might_ find an answer sooner by just trying it out yourself

Comment: As @rajan.kali said, you can simply use the `if/else` to compare the api level but keep in mind to check whether the variable `gatt != null` before accessing it. However, most of the devices have moved to latest api levels, supporting devices < 18 would do you no good, as lowest of device also now supports api level 21.

Comment: @a_local_nobody, I hoped that there is an answer in terms of the java standard. And how can I test it if I don't have such an old phone?

Comment: `And how can I test it if I don't have such an old phone?` by making an emulator, you'd perhaps be able to test most of the stuff you want to by just using a really old emulator

Comment: @DarShan, does a device "move" to another API level? I thought the Android versions were hardly connected to an API level, e.g. Android 4.0 is API 14. Was I wrong?

Comment: To be honest, I mistrust emulators. I think many of them are full with sloppy assumptions about architecture behaviour in edge cases.

Comment: @Kolodez Move as in OTA Updates & Default Factory APIs are at-least 21 now.

Comment: @Kolodez You can try Firebase Test Lab, it might have some older api versions to test.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I read more about these Android-specific OTA API updates?